# Not able to filter out a value in jsonPath

Tags: jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am working on JSONPath where I need to fetch a value for a particular country below is the given JSON.

`

But it is not working.

I am expecting to fetch  for a particular country like Canada, United States

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7574461/lucas-nguyen-17 could you please help her

Answer (score 1):

Your path should be

```
$.internationalControlDetails.[?(@.address.country=='Canada')].locationControlId
```

Note the `address` in the local path.

Everything else looks right.